# Скрипт проверки скорости исходящего интернет-соединения

Tags: javascript

как из кода узнать скорость исходящего соединения?

с входящим все понятно, вычисляем скорость скачивания эталонного файла, а как узнать исходящий?

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: Качаем файл, считаем время, делим размер на время.

Comment: это входящий канал, а я спрашиваю об исходящем

Comment: А какая разница? Качаем не **оттуда**, а **туда**.

Comment: Если реальный файл качать неохота, можно просто случайных данных программно нагенерить.